# Getting all identical content between 2 List<String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am currently able to get the total number of identical string value between my list of string using this.

```
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(yourFriendList);
        set.addAll(requestModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).list);

 int count = (yourFriendList.size() + requestModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).list.size()) - set.size());
```

But now I want to get all of this identical value and put it in a new variable List.

```
 List 1 : a b c d e f g
 List 2 : a h i e d j k
```

identical count is 3
identical string are a d e;

Comment: Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Set stores only non identical entries... You could use some other collections for displaying identical strings however.

Comment: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(set);`

Comment: "Getting all identical content between 2 List<String> ".... first source should be to look into the documentation --> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are describing an intersection between two lists.

This will work:

```
List<String> list1 = ...
List<String> list2 = ...

List<String> intersection = list1.stream()
                               .filter(item -> list2.contains(item))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Then this intersection variable will get all identical value between list 1 and 2?